# Returns True if string s has no substring of 3 same chars in a row; else False

Tags: python-3.x

I need to find the sub string whereas 'aaahfnalks' would be considered False, as 'aaa' would be the 3 consecutive characters. I'm not looking for the consecutive of '1,2,3,etc'.

I've tried running through a few for loops, and ranges but haven't been able to figure out how to address the issue within the sub string.

```
'''
prev_pwds = [ 'abc112233xyz', 'bat23man' ]
 test_strs = [ 'aabb12cc', 'a123b', 'a1234546b', 'a1234546b0',
 'abcdef1pqrstuvwx', 'abcdef1pqrstuvw', '1222345',
 'bat23man' ]

L = prev_pwds
s = test_strs

def pwdSpec_seq(s): # checks to see if there are 3 consecutive numbers or letters
  for i in s:
    for x in [i]:
      if x == x+1 == x+2:
        print (False)
  else: print(True)
'''
```

Result would go through the index of the string in a for loop and deliver something like this (I have the presentation code already formatted)

```
 pwdSpec_seq('a1234546b0') --> True
 pwdSpec_num('a1234546b0') --> True
 pwdSpec_ends('a1234546b0') --> False
 pwdSpec_len('a1234546b0') --> True
```

**next**

```
 pwdSpec_seq('abcdef1pqrstuvwx') --> True
 pwdSpec_num('abcdef1pqrstuvwx') --> True
 pwdSpec_ends('abcdef1pqrstuvwx') --> True
 pwdSpec_len('abcdef1pqrstuvwx') --> True
```

Comment: you said it is supposed to return `false` only i the case where a character is repeated three times. In your example `pwdSpec_ends('a1234546b0') --> False` but there is no character repeating consequtively 3 times

Comment: test_strs = '1222345',

Comment: for passwords it will be good if you consider regex operations

Answer (score 0, accepted):

there are a few formatting issues here.

`for x in [i]:` will create a list with a single element, and that element will be the entire string. If you instead use `for x in i:`, you'll loop through each character in the string which is what I believe you were trying.

Your second issue is `if x == x+1 == x+2`. 'char' + 'int' is not a valid operation, and in languages where it is it would give you the character that comes next in the ascii table, not the next element in a list you are no longer referencing.

Sticking with your current approach, I would suggest something like

```
def pwdSpec_seq(passwords): # checks to see if there are 3 consecutive numbers or letters
  for password in passwords:
    for ind, char in enumerate(password[:-2]):
      if password[ind + 1] == char and password[ind + 2] == char:
        print(False)
        break
  else:
    print(True)
```

`enumerate()` will give you the index in the list, and `[:-2]` skips the last 2 chars of the password to avoid an index out of bounds error. `for..else` blocks trigger the else if the loop completes without a `break`, so you'll want to break after printing

Comment: Thank you very much, your explanation was perfect!